# Check if 1 hour has passed from SQL Server Datetime column string C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to check if 1 hour ha passed from string `Datetime` that I have in SQL Server database. I tried this code but it didn't work or I didn't understand it right.

What I'm trying to do is to take the column Datetime value and check if passed 1 hour from `TimeDate.Now`.

Here is my code :

```
using (var GetLastPost = new SqlCommand("SELECT PostDate FROM Accs2 WHERE Username LIKE @user1", con))
{
    GetLastPost.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user1", ecid);

    using (var LastReader = await GetLastPost.ExecuteReaderAsync())
    {
        if (!LastReader.HasRows || !LastReader.Read())
        {
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime k = Convert.ToDateTime(LastReader["PostDate"].ToString());

            if (k > DateTime.Now)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Your Money is in the Box");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("1 Hour Not Passed yet");
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _It didn't work_ is very little information to go on. What didn't work? How didn't it work? When you debug this, what value does `k` take?

Comment: What do you think `k > DateTime.Now` does?

Comment: k is the value of coulmn from DateTime type that i have in my table
what im trying to do is to check if this coulmn value(PostDate) as passed/coparte 1 hour from Datetime.Now 
im sorry for my bad english

Comment: Which message box is displayed with your current code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya im reciving "Your money is in the box" but when i check in my database string and copration with my clock its not true ... and supposed to return "1 hour didnt past yet" 
what i want to get that if hour passed then put and return wait 1 more hour like some loop that can be done 1 time in hour

Comment: Did you debug the code? What value are you getting in `k`? Also can you share the sample value of PostDate? `(k > DateTime.Now)` will never be true if you have old date in the db. So either you have wrong data in db or k is having  wrong value. `if (k.AddHours(1) > DateTime.Now)` is the correct check

Comment: What is the type of `PostDate` in the database?

Comment: @mjwills the type is DateTime Type and the text i have there now is this time sting 07/03/2018 21:49:59 (UTCnow time)

Comment: @mjwills i think i didnt explain my self very well
what i want to do is when user trying to get box he can take this box 1 time in hour so when he took box i want to insert to user PostDate database new datetime that the user need to wait 1 hour again , and again and again like this

Answer (score 2):

A simple method would be something like

```
public bool HasAnHourPassed(DateTime compareTime)
{
    var timePassed = DateTime.Now - compareTime;
    return timePassed.TotalHours > 1;
}
```

Comment: Even easier and likely better to just do it in the SQL command itself: `SELECT PostDate from Accs2 where Username like @user1 AND DATEDIFF(hour,SYSDATETIME(),PostDate)  > 1`

Comment: im sorry but i didnt understand how to insert this line to my code 
my goal is if time as passed msgbox("money in the box") if time didnt past msgbox("only" : timePassed minutes left until next box)

Comment: @dodexahedron That unfortunately _assumes_ the SQL box and the application box have synchronized clocks, are in the same time zone, etc. Hth..

Comment: @Avnego, you would simply call this method where you are trying your if statement.

Comment: @EdSF If that is not the case, and if there's a chance the users/web servers/client applications/whatever themselves are not all in the same time zone, then DateTimeOffset should be used anyway, or else there will always be a problem.